# Illustrator toolbars glued together

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Adobe illustrator and i don't really know how to search for my errors.

At the right of my screen i have some 'toolbars' (like pathfinder, swatches, ..) you can enable them by clicking on the 'window' option at the top and then selecting them. So i was arranging them at the right of my screen, when all of the sudden (i must have done something wrong) the pathfinder, swatches, color toolbars are sticking together and i can't 'unstick' them.

Also when i deselect one of them under the 'window' option all of them disappear.

They also don't expand the the bottom of the screen inside a container like element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click, hold and drag the pathfinder or the menu of your choice to unstick them